# Converting excel to event format using eventlog() in R

Tags: r, business-process-management

I have uploaded a csv file in R as shown below. After importing the file, I converted it in a data frame and tried to convert it into an eventlog for process analyses using bupaR package and eventlog(). However, I just cannot understand how the excel gets converted into the event format. Please see the script I used. Once the data gets converted into an event log, I want to use the below function to create a process map chart which currently is giving an error. Please help.

```
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
process_search = read.csv("process.csv",header = T)
eventlog(
    case_id = "case",
    activity_id = "activity",
    timestamp = "timestamp",
    resource_id = "status"
)

process_search %>%process_map()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few things: 
Each of your cases are likely comprised of multiple steps required to process each individual invoice (ie. Get Invoice, Review Invoice, Pay Invoice). The different steps in your business process will be your "activity_id".

You also need to change how you are using "resource" and "timestamp" values.  Within each case, each element of "activity_id" should have a beginning and ending time.  This is how bupaR will calculate durations of each activity, and of each trace.  If your data is arranged to only have timestamps of when an activity began, you can use the beginning time as the "timestamp" for the Start "lifecycle_id", and the beginning time of the next activity as the "timestamp" for the Ending "lifecycle_id".

Additionally, bupaR needs to know what values case and activity pairs are unique, this is your "activity_instance_id".  One way to do this is to increment an integer for each unique (case, activity_id) combination.

Also, "resource_id" is intended to be the person or team responsible for each "activity_id".  Typically, this will be a userID or something similar and lets you look at efficiency of resources for different activities.

Here's an example of how your eventlog creation should look like:

```
eventlog(.,
       case_id = "case",
       activity_id = "activity",
       activity_instance_id = "recordIndex", #new incrementing integer
       lifecycle_id = "lifecycle_id", #new column with Start/End strings
       timestamp = "timestamp",
       resource_id = "resource_id") #new column with userID doing activity
```